# Pandas box plot error on one datapoint

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm working on a box-plot using pandas.

My DataFrame looks like this

```
Year                 2013      2014      2015      2016      2017
dfMin            1.091603  0.973346  1.040000  0.855209  1.079500
dfLowerQuartile  1.727191  1.684009  1.275601  1.136703  2.262654
dfUpperQuartile  2.225000  2.000000  1.857570  2.120644  2.435724
dfMax            2.687323  2.350000  2.105000  2.250000  2.566467
```

My chart code looks like this

```
chartDF.boxplot(grid=False, figsize=(9,4))
```

Leading to a plot looking like this
[image]

I am puzzled at the lower value in 2017 coming out as a point.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Your minimum value for 2017 is more than 1.5 IQR below the first quartile of the four provided data points, in which case the minimum is displayed as an outlier (a point).

From [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html) for `whis` in `boxplot` (*emphasis mine*):

> `whis` : float, sequence, or string (default = 1.5)
>
> As a float, determines the reach of the whiskers to the beyond the first and third quartiles. In other words, where IQR is the interquartile range `(Q3-Q1)`, the upper whisker will extend to last datum less than `Q3 + whis*IQR)`. Similarly, the lower whisker will extend to the first datum greater than `Q1 - whis*IQR`. **Beyond the whiskers, data are considered outliers and are plotted as individual points**. Set this to an unreasonably high value to force the whiskers to show the min and max values. Alternatively, set this to an ascending sequence of percentile (e.g., [5, 95]) to set the whiskers at specific percentiles of the data. **Finally, `whis` can be the string `'range'` to force the whiskers to the min and max of the data**.

So if you want the whiskers to extend all the way,

```
df.boxplot(grid=False, figsize=(9, 4), whis='range')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the outlier feature :)

Comment: @HenrikPoulsen but remember, the indices `dfLowerQuartile` and `dfUpperQuartile` in your dataframe are not interpreted by the boxplot function, it is just a value as another! Shuffling the values would not change the final plot at all.

Comment: Cool feature. Although if not careful one might be disguising outliers when in fact there are outliers in the data.

Comment: @Sosel raises a good point here - I presumed that you gave us nice quartiles because you knew the significance of them for boxplots... keep in mind that `boxplot` _does not_ - it just interprets each value as a data point.

Comment: Basically i took formatted data from another source, I'll try taking data directly from the underlying db, save myself a few steps. But as far as outliers go, the data is clean, and we have a desire to show the spread in order ro illustrate a few points, that as well as the fact that our data from 2017 is incomplete (we are measuring sales prices amongst 8000 businesses that mostly repirt in once pr year)

Comment: @HenrikPoulsen Cool, just wanted to be sure you were aware of that. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

What happens with the following?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 2.1, 2.3]})
df.boxplot()
```

It calcualtes out of these four values the quantiles, the value 1 is interpreted as an outlier. So: the actual indices you are using are ignored, pandas takes those values as data points.

So, actually, instead of setting min, max and quantiles yourself, you rather should pass the full data from a dataframe to a boxplot.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this

Answer (score 1):

It isn't issue. Basically boxplot show values around means. And if u have one point out of rectangle it means that point with that value is outlier.

More infromation about outliers: [Outlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier)

Answer (score 1):

This is an outlier for 2017. If you are not interested in that observation you should simply delete it in the dataset knowing that it will change values for the respective statistical measures.